# Getting remote values in ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I have the following script:

```
ssh ip@host /bin/bash << EOF
hostname # Print the remote hostname
A=`hostname`
echo \${A} # Print the local hostname
EOF
```

I want to get vaules from the remote server and use them as variables in the script (In this example `hostname`, But actually i need other things).

When i assign the value into a variable, I always get the local value instead of the remote value. What could be the issue? Please advise.

Comment: As in quote the EOF: `<<< "EOF"` and unescape the `\${A}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command substitution

```
`hostname`
```

is being evaluated inside the (unquoted) here document before the command is passed to the remote server. To have it evaluate on the remote server you need to escape it in the same way that you escaped the variable substitution `\${A}`

```
ssh ip@host /bin/bash << EOF
hostname
A=\`hostname\`
echo \${A}
EOF
```

or (better, replacing the deprecated backtick form of command substitution)

```
ssh ip@host /bin/bash << EOF
hostname
A=\$(hostname)
echo \${A}
EOF
```

or (best - since you don't appear to want *any* local expansion), quote the heredoc itself:

```
ssh ip@host /bin/bash << 'EOF'
hostname
A=$(hostname)
echo ${A}
EOF
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for this.

hn=$(ssh username@domain "hostname");echo "hostname is: $hn"

hostname is: [remote-name]

The command you want to run in quotes runs the command on the remote server. Your thing is just running the command on your local system. You have to tell ssh that is what you want to do.

Otherwise for more complex commands, see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-local-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine

> If Machine A is a Unix-based system, you can use:
>
> ```
> ssh root@MachineB 'bash -s' < local_script.sh
> ```

In general I find trying to cram stuff onto a command line is not a good idea, usually you want to run a local script that contains the logic and lets you control the output more readily.

Note the -s for bash.

Also note the comments in that response, which I won't repeat here, further qualifiers, does the command require root/sudo, etc.

When asking questions here, the more relevant details you provide on the question, the less guessing people have to do about what you actually want to achieve. Remember, nobody knows what you want to do unless you tell them clearly in words.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But it's not what i'm looking for. The `hostname` was just a simple example for my question. Actually i have a huge script inside the `EOF` and i need the assign some values from the remote server and use them in the script. However, I'm not able the assign remote values inside a variables, As it always gives me the local value.

Comment: then you should ask what you want the answer for, otherwise you won't get the answer you wanted. Correct your question to more accurately represent the actual thing you want running, in a simplified form.

Comment: I need to run `command -v mysql` (or any other command), but it must be inside the `EOF` as i need to use the output.